Compiler error E2134 starts after a month of compiling without any errors
I am testing the DelphiEncryptionCompendium repository.
When I load the project group, I can compile it fine. However, when I have the source folder in my search path and I and attempt to use the units in my project, I get a compiler error:

[dcc64 Error] DECCipherInterface.pas(762): E2134 Type '<void>' has no type info

The error is also on a weird location:

I have had this code in my project for a few weeks, and it started generating problems today.

Something has changed. What is it?

@DavidHeffernan, I had "Emit run-time type information" on,  in my project, changed it to off and the error is gone. Thanks for the hint!!!!
